# Android: webview is not opening a particular URL

Tags: android, url, webview, webviewclient

I have a webview which can open any url that I specify except this which I wanted to open.
http://www.witnext.in/witnext/#home.php

I googled so many articles about this and tried all but it works for all url except the above link.
I don't know whats wrong with this url.
Please if possible use the said url in your code and let me know are you able to open the same url.

FYI:-

- I have set the internet access permission in manifest.
- There is no error message in logcat.
- Min SDK ver 8, Target SDK ver 17
- Tested the same code with another url like google, facebook and it
  works.
- Above said url contains AJAX for smooth content loading.
- Above url is getting opened in the stock browser as expected.

Code

```
wvMain = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wvMain);
wvMain.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
wvMain.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
wvMain.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
wvMain.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
wvMain.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
wvMain.getSettings().setCacheMode(
android.webkit.WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
wvMain.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
wvMain.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
wvMain.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
wvMain.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
wvMain.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
view.loadUrl(url);
return true;
}
wvMain.loadUrl("http://www.witnext.in/witnext/#home.php");
```

Comment: try opening this url in android default browser

Comment: did u try open it into default browser of your device ??

Comment: Ya its getting opened in the default browser.I have mentioned same in my post. I have reported the same in android developer bug reporting section. @SourabhSaldi You can find the more detail in below link http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=56834